# Пишу стихи, но не понимаю, где ставить запятые. Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно я поставила запятые в стихе? И где они ещё нужны?

Спасибо за песни, спасибо за всё,
Согрел, покорил ты сердце мое.
Песни твои люблю я сердечно,
Твой голос, буду любить бесконечно.

Answer (score 5):

Другие запятые не нужны.
В последней строчке лишняя запятая: *буду любить (что?) твой голос.*
Вместо второй запятой (что не является ошибкой) я бы поставил тире в качестве связи благодарности с последующими словами.

*Спасибо за песни, спасибо за всё —

Согрел, покорил ты сердце мое.

Песни твои люблю я сердечно,

Твой голос буду любить бесконечно.*

Comment: Да, тире здесь к месту

Comment: @Александр Стрелец А как вы думаете, зачем автор поставил лишнюю запятую, ведь очевидной произносительной паузы там вроде бы нет. У меня есть версия, но я в ней не уверена.

Comment: @Sharon Вообще, это не телефонный разговор... Но если предположить, что _твой голос_ относится к первой части предложения  (_Песни твои люблю я сердечно, твой голос_), то тогда нужно поставить точку. А затем новое предложение: _Буду любить бесконечно_ .  Это грамматически верно, нестандартно, но читается плохо.

Comment: По-моему, такая трактовка вряд ли имеет смысл. Я думаю, что там такое членение речи с паузами: Песни твои // люблю я сердечно,
Твой голос //  буду любить бесконечно.  С размером в этих двух строках всё в порядке? Количество слогов разное,  может, какая пауза-цезура нужна?  А про телефон я не поняла...

Comment: @Sharon Насчет времён. Во втором предложении ведь настоящее и будущее, а в первом только прошедшее (там нет глаголов в настоящем). По поводу размера - да, не всё там гладко. А про телефон - не могу здесь писать.

Comment: А спасибо  говорится  сейчас, в настоящем времени.

Comment: Конечно, с присоединением _твоего голоса_ к первой части - это так, гипотетически. Про спасибо понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, я поддержу **первый ответ**, добавив некоторые комментарии.

Стих разделен на два предложения, которые различаются  **по времени**: (1)  настоящее и прошедшее время и (2) настоящее и будущее время. Рассматривать их следует отдельно, точка вполне на месте.

Первое предложение – бессоюзное сложное (БСП), здесь можно поставить **запятую, тире или двоеточие**.  Каждый знак четко определяет свою семантику и интонацию. Запятая обозначает последующее раскрытие темы, тире – взаимообусловленность двух высказываний, а двоеточие точно указывает  пояснительный характер именно второй части.

**Но двоеточие** (с его длительной пояснительной паузой) сюда как-то  не вписывается, а тире – это как раз то, что нужно. Интонационно вторая часть будет выделена больше, чем при постановке запятой. Но в конечном итоге  запятая или тире – это **авторский** выбор.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо второй запятой можно поставить и двоеточие.
Спасибо за песни, спасибо за всё: (а именно)
Согрел, покорил ты сердце мое.
Тогда это будет БСП, где 2 часть содержит пояснение, за что именно благодарят.
А можно и точку поставить. Ведь "Согрел, покорил ты сердце мое" - это явно не всё, за что выражают благодарность.